# How is markdown in discussions being converted to HTML?

Tags: support, markdown-rendering, discussions-space

Posts on SE use Markdig on the server side, and markdown-it for the client-side preview. But it seems like threads under discussions are behaving slightly differently. For example, underscores and angle brackets inside backtick-delimited inline code are treated as markup and not as their literal characters. Why? How is the markdown to HTML rendering for this thing working?

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems you might be mistaken about something? Here's [what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kcz2O.png) on the discussion post you're probably talking about. Maybe the issue is that you're using the rich text mode of the new editor? It seems like it has some special behaviour for things that look like markdown (I don't know why it decides to do that even after considering itself a "rich-text" editor)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat no, that's my attempt to make it keep my angle brackets. With or without backslashes it literally strips things like `` `hello_<world>` `` into `` `hello_` ``. I'm using the markdown mode of the new editor- not the fancy editor mode. And now I find out that comments don't support commonmark multi-backtick inline code. great. my day is even more ruined.

Comment: From what I see from the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77979515/revisions) it seems that your reply ended up having no angular brackets at all, so its probably not the markdown rendering at fault but instead that something is stripping them out.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat actually, that's a good point. so maybe there's sanitization of the markdown before rendering, which would be something new I think, but I'm still interested in the answer to this question as it is asked.